# What is the answer to this recursive function?

Tags: java, sorting, recursion, data-structures, computer-science

This is the method for merge-sort:

```
    private void doMergeSort(int lowerIndex, int higherIndex) {

        if (lowerIndex < higherIndex) {

        int middle = lowerIndex + (higherIndex - lowerIndex) / 2;

        System.out.println("Lower index="+lowerIndex+"   Middle="+middle+ "   Higher index="+higherIndex);

        doMergeSort(lowerIndex, middle);

        doMergeSort(middle + 1, higherIndex);

        mergeParts(lowerIndex, middle, higherIndex);//never mind this method
    }
}
```

The output for doMergeSort(0,9) is as given below:

```
    Lower index=0   Middle=4   Higher index=9
    Lower index=0   Middle=2   Higher index=4
    Lower index=0   Middle=1   Higher index=2
    Lower index=0   Middle=0   Higher index=1
    Lower index=3   Middle=3   Higher index=4//This line
    Lower index=5   Middle=7   Higher index=9
    Lower index=5   Middle=6   Higher index=7
    Lower index=5   Middle=5   Higher index=6
    Lower index=8   Middle=8   Higher index=9
    4 11 23 28 43 45 65 77 89 98 //never mind this part too
```

How did the 4th line of the output(as marked with comment) come into existence? Please explain.

Comment: That's the second recursive call made from ``doMergeSort(0,4)``: middle is calculated as 2, so you make calls (0,2) and (3,4).  Why do you have a problem with this?

Comment: Do you have a problem stepping through the code? If you put a break point at the println, you can see the call stack of the recursion when that particular line is printed.

Comment: @jasonharper So does that mean the functions doMergeSort(0,4) and doMergeSort(3,4) are both executed at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the diagramatic representation of the control flow of your code which will help you to get your doubt cleared.

[image]

Comment: I see, but why doesn't func(5,9) execute as a sibling to func(0,4)?